# Instant sync for packaged apps

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, synchronization, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I have a packaged app that uploads files to a folder in google drive.

When the drive folder content changes (for example because the user uploads a file using the windows client of my app), I want to be able to automatically sync the folder on my packaged app.

Of course I could do this with polling, but that way the api quota might be exceeded pretty quickly.

Is there any way I can be notified of any changes in the google drive folder?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Drive API push notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push). It will let you watch for changes to resources. You can use this feature to improve the performance of your application. It also allows you to eliminate the extra network and compute costs involved with polling resources. With this push notification, the Drive API notifies your application whenever a watched resource changes.

Hope it helps you.